# PHP reading out a realm.io file

Tags: php, swift, realm

I'm planning a simple CRUD application in Swift and I would like to use realm.io for saving data to the local device and storing it on the realm mobile platform which is on a separate server. Is it possible to query on the realm mobile platform database using PHP?

Comment: Sorry, but this question is impossible to answer in a meaningful way. Obviously it is possible to read a file with php. What do you expect us to answer?

Comment: Asking for software/libraries is EXPLICITLY off-topic. If you mean "read realm.io" as in "read the bytes", yes. you can do that with ANY programming language that has file input/output. If you mean "read realm.io" as in "run a query on the database", then you'd need a specific interface/library for that, and as stated earlier - that's off-topic.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to run a query on a realm.io database with PHP and was wondering if it's possbile. I edited my above question a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm Mobile Database is not available for PHP, but you can build your mobile apps on Swift and sync data with Realm Mobile Platform, learn more at https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform and https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the Realm Mobile Platform is not readable with PHP? Is there another way I can display the data in a web interface?

Comment: @SjorsvanDongen currently not, from the Docs: "Sync available for Realm Java, Realm Objective‑C & Realm Swift. Coming soon for Realm React Native & Realm Xamarin."

Comment: Thank you, that's all I wanted to know :)